# El $this->config->set_item no me cambia el valor de la variable en el config.php - CODEIGNITER

Tags: php, codeigniter

El `$this->config->set_item` no me cambia el valor de la variable en el `config.php`

**Código en el controlador:**

```
$premisa1 = $this->input->post('numero_premisas');
$this->config->set_item('premisass',$premisa1);
```

**Código en el `config.php`:**

```
$config['premisass'] = '1';
```

En el `config.php` inicio la variable en 1 pero con la instruccion del controlador deberia actulizarse ese valor y no lo hace

Comment: El archivo no cambiara porque cambies el valor de la configuración en tiempo de ejecución. La configuración es el comportamiento que tu aplicativo tiene por default.

Comment: ¿Pero entonces como puedo cambiar el valor de esa variable `premisass` porque tengo entendido que `set_item` sirve para eso? ¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Pues eso con set_item, haz un echo $config['premisass'] a ver que te pone. De todas formas, eso no te sobreescribe en el config.php, lo que hace es cambiar el valor de $config['premisas'] que ya está previamente cargada en memoria. Pero por lo que veo, dices que está en el archivo a 1, y con set_item lo estás poniendo a 1 tambien...